# android development: App Error Problems

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have an android app that is on Google Play and I have a few people who have reported this error. But I have no idea what it means and what is going wrong. If someone could help me and tell me what the problem is or has any suggestions that would be great. Thank you for your help.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.media.MediaPlayer.add_mm_settings(MediaPlayer.java:1855)
 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:798)
 at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:225)
 at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:49)
 at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:482)
 at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:551)
 at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1949)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1600)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1321)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4306)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: anyone know whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem as well.   Adding the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission to my AndroidManifest.xml solved this problem.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```